# We have purchased "AZURE AD PREMIUM P2" but we are not able to use this subscription

Tags: azure

We have purchased "AZURE AD PREMIUM P2" but we are not able to use this subscription, as when i access azure portal, i will get this message to purchase a subscription:-

[image]

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the default home screen, and the message on the left is a **trial offer** referring to an **Azure subscription** for resources such as *virtual machines, SQL databases, function apps, etc.* which is separate from an **Azure AD tenant/subscription**.

You can see your Azure AD license by:

1. Opening the **Azure Active Directory** blade
2. See your Azure AD license level from the basic information on the overview page

[image]

Comment: ok fine, so i got `License Azure AD Premium P2` .. will this be sufficient to create key vaults and host some web apps?

Comment: @johnGu No, those are Azure resources which are not related to Azure AD at all. You create those resources in an Azure subscription

Comment: so what type of license best suites our need? we need mainly to create key valuts and web apps .. thanks